# Can I hide the particular column in jquery like this?

Tags: jquery

I am hiding the entire column in the grid like this?

```
$('#Grid tr th').each(function(column) {
     if ($(this).is('#div.id')) {
            hide();
     }
});
```

Can I do like this?

Comment: i think you need to post your HTML code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do something like:

```
$('#Grid tr').each(function() {
         $(this).find('td:eq(0)').hide();
});
```

Where the number in eq() is the column numbers index (starts from zero). You may also user :first or :last instead of :eq().

You may also use this approach:
for the first column:

```
$("#Grid td:first-child").hide();
```

for any column with index from 1 (!) in [nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$("#Grid td:nth-child(1)").hide();
```

for last column:

```
$("#Grid td:last-child").hide();
```

**For hiding also the title in thead** you can use comma separated selectors:

```
$("#Grid tbody td:nth-child(2), #Grid thead th:nth-child(2)").hide();
```

or

```
$("#Grid tbody td:nth-child(1)").hide();
$("#Grid thead th:nth-child(1)").hide();
```

or for the first approach:

```
$('#Grid tr').each(function() {
         $(this).find('td:eq(0), th:eq(0)').hide();
});
```

see the updated example at: 
http://www.alexteg.se/stackoverflow/jquery_hide_table_column.html

Comment: See the two approaches and the test page above. There must be something you are doing wrong, as it works fine for me.

Comment: can we hide the jquery grid column with column name and contents?
thanks

Comment: Sure, I have updated the post above and the testpage. Just use comma separation like in CSS. The jQuery selectors behave more or less like CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
 $('#Grid tr th').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == "#div") {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
```

You may want to replace the `#div` with the one you are using.

Comment: But its still showing me? initially I did visible false for that column once user select from hided column I need to make hide
or I need to make read only for that column?
thnks

Comment: "#div" wouldn't be in the attribute id, I think you meant "div"

Answer (score 0):

> let's say i want to hide the 17th col. of the grid

```
 var colindex =16;

   $("#CP_Main_gvPOItems").find("th:nth-child(" + colindex + "), td:nth-child(" + colindex + ")").hide();
```